# newbie Xubuntu NIC driver issue

Tags: drivers, wireless, xubuntu, ethernet

I'm not sure how well this question will be received by the community, but here goes :(

- I really, really suck with computers. I have almost no idea what I'm doing, and I have a really strong desire to get this area of my life handled.
- My friend partition my hard drive (I think) and installed a version of Xubuntu, however I can't connect this to the internet
- Apparently this was quite a common problem for Realtek NICs, so with an ethernet connection I thought I fixed it! Actually, I didn't. It resulted in my laptop not being able to connect using the ethernet either!
- So now I have no idea how to proceed. Even if I logged on to print out the common lscpi commands or /etc/blacklist.modprobe.d things, is there a way to copy and paste them onto this forum without internet connection? Maybe I'll put them on a usb stick?
- I'm currently using some version of Windows 10. I really want to invest time into learning how to use Linux, but how does a complete idiot start out? What methods should I use- and how do I know if I'll improve at all? I'm feeling really beaten down and unmotivated.

I tried reading other answers but to be honest I have real trouble understanding and following what everybody is talking about.

Comment: Try out http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/ubuntu-an-absolute-beginners-guide/

Comment: Plug in USB drive, it should automatically recognize and you should get an icon of a drive.  Open terminal, open text editor, run ` sudo lshw -C network` in terminal, copy output to text editor, save text to USB...post it here. Done